# How to define hashcode and equals if your object only consists of interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, hashcode

let's assume I have a little (java) class that simply consist of 3 interface objects. These 3 objects together make up a key value for a map. Now my quesion is: how to define equals and hashcode for that class ? I mean, all members of that class are just interfaces who doesn't implement anything ?

Example:

```
class SomeKey {
  public SomeKey(SomeWeiredInterface1 a, SomeWeiredInterface2 b,     SomeWeiredInterface3 c){
    ....
}
}
```

The most straight forward way would be:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
SomeKey otherKey = (SomeKey)other;  

return a.equals.otherKey.a && b.equals.otherKey.b && c.equals.otherKey.c;
}
```

To me it looks like it's simply not possible, or at least I have to write these methods on my own, because I can't use (or delegate) any hashcode or equals methods of the implementation of these interfaces ?

Thanks for any hints!
Thorsten

Comment: Why not?  You can call `equals` and `hashCode` on those objects perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, so equals or hashCode is executed on the object the implements the interface? That would make sense ;-)   But on the other hand, equals and hashCode are not part of the interface definition?!

Comment: Yes and yes.  So what?  You can still call `equals` and `hashCode` on objects typed as an interface that doesn't define those methods.

Comment: But why? Can I call equals and hashCode on an interface object because both methods are part of Object.class "basic" methods? And if there is a more specific implementation of hashCode or equals in the interfaces implementing class, that equals or hashCode method is called, and otherwise the one of Object.class ?

Comment: Yes and yes.  Did you try it?

Comment: Every implementation of any interface extends `java.lang.Object`. It "is-a" `Object`, and you can call `Object` methods on it too.

Comment: @erickson: thanks for that explanation. If this wouldn't work the way it does, implementing against interfaces wouldn't realy make sense.

Answer (score 2):

All interfaces implicitly declare all the public methods from the `Object` class (see [JLS § 9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2)). You can call the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your interface types, and it will call the overridden methods in whatever concrete class implements the interface, or it will call the default implementations of those methods inherited from `Object`.

You can write the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of `SomeKey` the same way, without regard for whether the field types are classes or interfaces:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof SomeKey)) return false;
    SomeKey other = (SomeKey)o;
    return a.equals(other.a) && b.equals(other.b) && c.equals(other.c);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return java.util.Objects.hash(a.hashCode(), b.hashCode(), c.hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the equals() and hashCode() methods generated automaticlly by my IDE:

```
public class SimpleClass {
private SimpleFirstInterface firstField;
private SimpleSecondInterface secondField;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    SimpleClass that = (SimpleClass) o;

    if (firstField != null ? !firstField.equals(that.firstField) : that.firstField != null) return false;
    return secondField != null ? secondField.equals(that.secondField) : that.secondField == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = firstField != null ? firstField.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (secondField != null ? secondField.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

}

These two methods are using inside of them the equals() and hashCode() methods of the interfaces implementations if they are provided there. If not, then standard implementation of Object's equals() and hashCode() will be used.

Comment: So, if SimpleFirstInterface  is implemented from class SimpleFirstInterfaceImpl, equals and hashCode from SimpleFirstInterfaceImpl are called. If SimpleFirstInterfaceImpl doesn't implement those functions the ones from Object are called ?

Comment: Yeah. Precisely. But if you want your HashMap to work effectively you should make a qualitative implementation of these methods and not to rely to the ones from Object.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use(**delegate**) equals and hashcode methods of implementation classes **but** yes, you **can't** rely on them.

The implementation classes may contain hashcode & equals which doesn't produce unique result for the same object or different hashcode for the same object.

I believe these 3 interfaces are **not** marker interface and has some methods which returns the state of the member variables of the implementation class.
If the above is true, then you can use the state in your own hashcode() & equals implementation.

See example:

```
Interface A{
   getValue();
}

Interface B{
   getData();
}

class AImpl implements A{
      private String value;

      public String getValue(){
            return value;
      }
}
class BImpl implements B{
      private int data;

      public int getData{
            return data;
      }
}

class SomeKey{

   private A value;
   private B data;

    //constructor
    public SomeKey(A value, B data){
         this.value = value;
         this.data = data;      
    }

 @Override
 public int hashcode(){
     int result = 1;
     result = 29 * result + value.hashcode();
     result = result + data.hashcode();
     return result;
 }
 //similarly override equals
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps something like overwriting the methods hashcode(), equals() and compareTo(), using the Comparable Interface. To try with other Interfaces.
I didn't read the answers above, of course well examples.

```
  private static class SomeString implements Comparable<SomeString> {
   private final String s;
   SomeString(final String s) {
   this.s = s;
  }

@Override
public int compareTo(final SomeString o) {
 return s.compareTo(o.s);
}
```

}

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(final Object o) {
  if(o == null) return false;
  if(this == o) return true;
  if(this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

  final SomeString o1 = (SomeString) o;
  return compareTo(o1) == 0;
 }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
   return s.hashCode();
  }
```